# How can I see which champions I got first?

Tags: league-of-legends

How can I see the first five champions I got in League of Legends?

Answer (score 2):

This information is not available, generally. Your profile only keeps track of who you've unlocked (a binary, "is available / is not available") without any additional information regarding *when*.

That said, if you've only purchased very few champions, it may be possible to check your history in the Riot Store... but given the nature of the question, I expect that your first 5 champions will have long been pushed off the history.

Comment: Interesting... I could swear I was able to see all the way back to my first purchase about half a year ago.

Comment: @3ventic That might be true for you, but I've been playing since Closed Beta, so it doesn't surprise me that some of my past purchase data is lost in some obscure database somewhere... :D

Comment: I started somewhere around season 1's beginning... I haven't played in months anymore and I have well over 150 purchases made. Weird that they changed it, but good to know.